# Is there any virtual keyboard solution for angular?

Tags: angularjs, keyboard, virtual-keyboard

Is there any virtual keyboard solution for angular which is completely compatible with angular ecosystem?
I have taken look at mottie keyboard with angular wrapper around it and also 
[This](http://the-darc.github.io/angular-virtual-keyboard/)
[and this](https://github.com/antonio-spinelli/ng-virtual-keyboard)

the first one is not fully angular, I mean it doesn't work well with validation system of angular, the two latter have very ugly UI and are not very customize able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use material design keyboard for good UI but this is also not so much customisable.
https://github.com/davidenke/angular-material-keyboard